# Symfony: Using "action" as a form field name causes issues

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a form type that has this field:

```
        ->add('action', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

The form type maps to an entity that has a property `action`.

The problem is when I render this form in twig, the field is pre-populated with the form's HTTP action URL, which is clearly not what I want.

Do I have to rename the form field and entity property to avoid this collision?

Answer (score 3):

I was incorrectly initializing the form in my controller. I was doing this:

```
    $filterForm = $this->createForm(new ActionLogFilterType(), array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin.action_logs.index'),
        'method' => 'GET',
    ));
```

When I needed to do this:

```
    $filterForm = $this->createForm(new ActionLogFilterType(), null, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin.action_logs.index'),
        'method' => 'GET',
    ));
```

So it turns out I can indeed use `action` as a form field as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.3 are the variables method and action added, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html. So, yes, you will have to rename it.

Comment: Actually you can use action, I made a mistake and provided an answer. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I understood your question as that you defined action as a property of the form itself, not adding it as a child of the form. Glad you solved your problem. :-)